# Print Element names in Console Use Firebug

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

I want to listing all input elements in console of firebug so in console window write the followings:

```
var inputs = $(":input");
console.log(inputs);
```

but when I press the Run in console appear `null`

also when I write just `var inputs = $(":input");` the console show `Undefined` I sure the page have a lot of input elements, where is the problem?

Comment: Going to need a sample page that this doesn't work on, it always works for me. You might try `$('input,textarea,select,button');` as this is what `:input` is short for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the provided snippet.

Though, without specifying what to write (using `console.log`) firebug will print whatever the last statement returned, when declaring a variable using `var` the result is always `undefined`.

```
var inputs = $(":input"); // firebug printing 'undefined' is valid
var abc = 123;            // results in the same thing
```

---

Please make sure that the website in question actually uses `jQuery` (bound to global `$`), and that there really are input elements present in the DOM.

Also make sure that the jQuery version running is of a version later/equal to 1.0 (`:input` selector didn't exists until then).

If it has jQuery it probably is of a more recent version, how ever; without you providing us with additional information there is no way to guarantee it.

Comment: that's right, I update new version of jQuery and references need to change, thank you

Comment: @Saeid problem solved or are there further issues? Please mark answer as accepted to flag this thread as solved if you got the answer you were looking for.

Comment: yes but there is a time limited to accept an answer and now I flag it.

Answer (score 0):

simply go to the firebug console and wrtie as @refp mentioned the page in question must have jquery included

```
 $(":input")
```

press run